# move intersecting objects until they no longer intersect

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision, intersection

If i have to still objects that are intersecting.

How do i find out how much I should move them by to stop them from touching each other?

I know how to tell which objects are intersecting (using java's intersects method.

I should also mention that all objects are in a list of objects (called objs bellow) ...

```
public void move(Object ob){
    // this rectangle surrounds the object I'll check against
    // all of the other objects below
    Rectangle objectToCheck = ob.getBounds();

    // Cycle through all the other objects and check if they
    // cross over the rectangle I created above
    for(Object obj : objs){
        // Creates a bounding rectangle that is used temporarily
        // for each other object on the board
        Rectangle otherObject= obj.getBounds();

        // Check if one object crosses over another object
        if(otherObject != objectToCheck && otherObject.intersects(objectToCheck)){
         // they intersect! now how do i know how much to move them so
         // that they no longer intersect? 
    }
```

Comment: What defines their movement, do you the code for that?

Comment: @ChrisCooney there is no movement (still objects on a canvas type setting), they are just drawn in a random location, but after they are drawn there, i just want to shift them around so that they don't touch each other ..

Comment: Are you also trying to ensure that the objects you move do not intersect each other when you move them? I assume so however I just wanted to ask.

Comment: @nattyddubbs yes absolutely - thanks for pointing that out, i forgot to mention it

Comment: When you get the X,Y coordinates of an object, is it the top left corner, like in other languages?

Comment: @ChrisCooney yes i believe so